# How to test carrierwave version size with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, carrierwave

I have a CarrierWave::Uploader that produces three version of the uploaded image.

```
# Process files as they are uploaded:                                                                  
   process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]                                                                   

   # Create different versions of your uploaded files:                                                    
   version :thumb do                                                                                      
     process :resize_to_fit => [60, 60]
   end

   version :small do
     process :resize_to_fit => [24, 24]
   end
```

And in my tests I try to verify the dimensions of the generated images

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'carrierwave/test/matchers'

describe 'manufacturer logo uploader' do
  include CarrierWave::Test::Matchers

  before(:each) do
    image_path = Rails.root.join('test/fixtures/images', 'avatar100.gif').to_s
    @manufacturer = Factory.create(:manufacturer, :page_status => 1)
    @manufacturer.logo_image = File.open(image_path)
    @manufacturer.save!
  end

  context "manufacturer logo dimensions" do
    it "should have three versions" do
      @manufacturer.logo_image.should have_dimensions(400,400)
      @manufacturer.logo_image.thumb.should have_dimensions(60,60)
      @manufacturer.logo_image.small.should have_dimensions(24,24)
    end
  end

end
```

but this test depends on the actual image and resize_to_fit will not necessarily resize it to the specified dimensions. Any ideas on how to test this using stubs?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress here?  I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @BenU No, I think I couldn't find a better solution

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, which actually processes an image. This is slower than stubs, but verifies the actual resize (as long as the input image is larger than the target size).

```
describe 'images' do

  include CarrierWave::Test::Matchers

  before do
    MyUploader.enable_processing = true
  end

  it 'are resized' do
    path = Rails.root.join *%w[ spec data sample.png ]
    my_model = FactoryGirl.create :my_model, image: path.open

    my_model.artwork.small.should be_no_larger_than(300, 400)
  end

  after do
    MyUploader.enable_processing = false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

long shot but can you try to add this

```
before do
  DocumentUploader.enable_processing = true
end
```

because processing (current version and other versions) could be turned off by default for performance reason

had similar problem related to `process set_file_name_to_model` that was doing something setting "file_name" on model attribute

http://ruby-on-rails-eq8.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/carrierwave-uploader-not-triggering.html